# how to add database events to google calendar using api

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

How to intergate google calender in php and put events from database in the calender? 
Here's My code:

```
<?php
include_once 'init.php';
require_once './google-api-php-client-2.1.0/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();
ob_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("app name");
$client->setDeveloperKey("api key");
?>
```

I don't have any idea whats next. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're not here to write code for you. We're here to help you with your code written by YOU. You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask